# Android BottomNavigationView slides

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigationview, bottomnavigationview

When I try to make a navigationview like this, whenever i change icons it slides and pushes others to other directions. how do I change this? I want to make it just grow a little.

[image: First Page]

[image: Second Page]

Comment: Did you find solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use this library: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

BottomNavigationView was recently introduced into the Support library as well, but I'm not sure if it has the effect you're trying to achieve...